# How do you install PHPUnit without using PEAR on Mac OS X 10.5?

Tags: php, phpunit, pear

I am having trouble installing PEAR, but I really only want to install PHPUnit. Does anyone have experience doing this?

Answer (score 8):

## Install via GIT

You can follow the instructions from the Git README: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/

### "git" the files and drop them in your home directory

```
cd ~ && mkdir phpunit && cd phpunit
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/dbunit.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-file-iterator.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-text-template.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-token-stream.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-timer.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium.git
```

### setup a personal binary path

```
cd ~ && mkdir bin
vi ~/.profile
>> export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
>> :wq
source ~/.profile
```

### create the executable

```
touch ~/bin/phpunit
chmod 755 ~/bin/phpunit
```

### write the executable

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

// set main method
define('PHPUnit_MAIN_METHOD','PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main');

// add phpunit to the include path
$paths = scandir($_ENV['HOME'].'/phpunit');
$includes = array();
foreach($paths as $path){
    if (!preg_match('/^\./', $path)){
        $includes[] = $_ENV['HOME'].'/phpunit/' . $path;
    }
}
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR,$includes).PATH_SEPARATOR.get_include_path());

// set the auto loader
require 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';

// execute
PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main();
```

### test the executable

```
which phpunit
phpunit --version
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [PHPUnit installation guide](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html):

> Although using the PEAR Installer is the only supported way to install PHPUnit, you can install PHPUnit manually. For manual installation, do the following:

1. Download a release archive from http://pear.phpunit.de/get/ and extract it to a directory that is listed in the include_path of your php.ini configuration file.
2. Prepare the phpunit script:

   1. Rename the phpunit.php script to phpunit.
   2. Replace the @php_bin@ string in it with the path to your PHP command-line interpreter (usually /usr/bin/php).
   3. Copy it to a directory that is in your path and make it executable (chmod +x phpunit).
3. Prepare the PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php script:

   1. Replace the @php_bin@ string in it with the path to your PHP command-line interpreter (usually /usr/bin/php).

Comment: How can I be sure that my PHP command line interpreter is located at /usr/bin/php?

Comment: Also, I've changed my include path multiple times trying to set up pear. What should the default be for Mac OS X 10.5?

Comment: `which php` should inform you which binary the system is implicitly using

Answer (score 0):

Andrew, I am wrestling with installing PHPUnit at the moment. Found out that it helps a lot if restart your Webserver after updating the include_path in php.ini.
Now looking for the exact location of the PHP command line interpreter (that is how I got here). I'll keep you informed.

Sabine

Answer (score 0):

I just installed it today. My steps were as follows:

- download from /get/ - I used 3.3.9.tgz
- extract all files into the pear directory (pear-phpunit, PHPUnit/, etc...)
- change the @php_bin@ to point to my php binary (/usr/bin/php) in the files mentioned above
- create a symlink from pear-phpunit to /usr/local/bin/phpunit ( `ln -s /usr/share/php/pear/pear-phpunit /usr/local/bin/phpunit` )

Answer (score 0):

I recently made a [github fork](https://github.com/gewthen/phpunit) of phpunit that currently works (mostly) without the use of pear. It might work for you.